# How to kill Firebird (2.1) attachment/connection if VPN was used for database session

Tags: firebird, vpn, database-deadlocks, firebird2.1

I am using VPN (Endpoint Security, Check Point) to establish connection to the Firebird 2.1 database from IBExpert on my computer. Sometimes I just forget disconnect from database and I cancel/disonnect VPN session only.

When I am connectiong once more to the VPN and database I can see in the mon$attachments that the previous connection/attachment is still existing and its unresolved transactions are causing deadlock errors (that belong to the previous attachment - this can be verified exactly by the transaction number that is reported in the error message of deadlock error).

So - VPN sometimes retains sessions and those VPN sessions keeps the Firebird attachments in existences.

Is there way how can I (using SYSDBA connection) end those other Firebird attachments from my current Firebird session?

I have contacted the VPN administrator to cancel VPN sessions, but it takes time. Database shutdown is out of the question - DB is in production mode. So, ending Firebird attachments using SQL is the only option left for me - if such option exists at all?

Comment: `I have contacted the VPN administrator to cancel VPN sessions,` - i don't get it. You say you already cancel the VPN session, why do you need an administrator to cancel it yet again? What should it even achieve?

Comment: I disconnected from the VPN network but my guess was that VPN can keep some kind of tunnel, connection, hanlde, I don't know. I know that Firebird removes mon$attachments from the disconnected connectsion. In my case I disconnected from VPN, but Firebird kept mon$attachments records, that means, that Firebird still has some senses for existing connection or some other kind of socket-related resource.

Comment: yep, that is what i suppose too. So perhaps you'd talk with your admin about VPN settings instead? So that if you intentionally disconnect it would break the connection on both sides? Or have some short timeout then break it. Or give you some tool to break your connections? Fixing VPN not Firebird. Then, there can be sense for VPN to retain imaginary connection when underlying real connection was lost. Like bad, interrupting phone connection. VPN can hide it and create illusion of continuos connection with sometimes very slow speed

Comment: However, this should not be happening when you properly do VPN disconnection (as opposed to underlying modem or other connection). When you command your VPN tool to break connection - it should do it on both ends. That's why i think you actually have VPN misconfiguration issue not FB misconfiguration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebird 2.5 and later, you can delete a connection from `MON$ATTACHMENTS` to kill a connection. This is not supported with the monitoring tables in Firebird 2.1 as far as I'm aware.

Given even Firebird 2.5 is end-of-life, and Firebird 2.1 has been end-of-life since 2014, you should really consider updating.

Normally, Firebird uses the SO_KEEPALIVE socket option to detect dead connections, but this can take a long time (depending on your OS configuration). An alternative might be to configure `dummy_packet_interval` in firebird.conf to a non-zero value (the value is seconds, so set it to a reasonable (read, not too low) value).